# JavaScripted Augmented Reality

Tags: javascript, augmented-reality

Does anyone have experience with a JavaScript library for Augmented Reality?
If so, can you recommend one?

**EDIT:**
Not sure how to better clarify this... By Augmented Reality I mean using device webcam (laptop, smartphone, tablet) and overlapping elements over the video feed on screen. Ofen, the overlapping is done based on a marker the algorithm searches for within each frame and makes calculations about its position in space.

Hope that's enough.

Thanks.

Comment: [AR.js](https://github.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js) is the best in my opinion, jsartoolkit/tango can used as a backend and can display A-Frame objects, ha strong support for three.js, and it can use babilon.js as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you might be looking for. JSARToolkit is a direct port of Flash FLARToolkit from Ilmari Heikkinen. Great tutorial you may also want to check out and a link to the Git repo.

http://weblog.bocoup.com/javascript-augmented-reality/

https://github.com/kig/JSARToolKit

Answer (score 1):

You can try [skarf.js](http://cg.skeelogy.com/skarfjs/), a framework that I have created for handling JavaScript augmented reality libraries in Three.js.

It currently integrates JSARToolKit and js-aruco, so you can easily switch between these two libraries to decide on the more suitable one to use.

This framework takes care of a number of things for you, including automatic loading of models when the associated markers are detected (association is specified in a JSON file). There is also a GUI marker system which allows users to control settings using AR markers.

Integration with Three.js is just one line of code to create a Skarf instance and another line of code to update.

There are videos, live demos, source codes, examples and documentation available. Check out http://cg.skeelogy.com/skarfjs/ for more info.